# Rider - evaluation of List is disabled. Use context menu to enable Problem

Tags: c#, rider, jetbrains-rider

I've been having trouble previewing the contents of my collection for a while now.

The message is:

> Count = Evaluation of System.Private.CoreLib : System.Collections.Generic.List<T> : get_Count () is disabled. Use context menu to enable

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, there is a 'Refresh' button. When I click it, I can see results, but when I move my mouse, the window disappears because the next window is smaller :/

How do I fix this? About 2 months ago, everything was working fine.
I have the newest version of Rider and my license is paid and active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try any of the following:

- Instead of just clicking `refresh`, right click on it and it will open a context menu. Select `Enable Evaluation Of Selected Item` in the dropdown
- Delete the `.idea` folder in the root of your project when Rider is not running, then open your project in Rider again and check if the issue is gone
- Update project to `.net6`

The problem has been reported as a bug in Rider's [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-74161).

Comment: I didnt have option 'Enable Evaluation Of Selected Item'. Deleting .idea directory worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove `<option>` entries (2 examples shown) from workspace.xml inside the .idea folder instead of deleting the folder, then restart Rider.

```
  <component name="DisabledMethodsStorage">
    <option name="disabledMethods">
      <set>
        <option value="mscorlib : System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;T&gt; : Contains (T)" />
        <option value="mscorlib : System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;T&gt; : get_Count ()" />
      </set>
    </option>
  </component>
```